# No Mouse/Keyboard interaction in new Ubuntu install with xfce4 (VirtualMachine)

Tags: xfce, vmware, vmware-tools

I'm running Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS in VMware-Workstation-12-Player.
I installed

```
sudo apt install xfce4
```

and

```
sudo apt install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
```

when I now start the X-Server by

```
startx
```

I see this screen
[image]

I can see the curser inside the VM (it turns black and a little smaller within the VM) so my mouse gets tracket. But Clicking or Keyboard input doesn't work. I can't even switch back to TTY by `CTRL`+`ALT`+`F<x>`.

Until today I never had a problem with this setup I used multiple times already (`Ubuntu` + `xfce4` + `open-vm-tools`).

Today VMware Workstation 12 Player was updated to Version 12.5.8 .. maybe it has something to do with that?

**How can I get mouse and keyboard to work?**

**NOTE**
I already tried:

- reboot
- removing open-vm-tools `sudo apt remove open-vm-tools* --purge`

Nothing changed

Comment: same problem here after reinstalling the gcc toolchain it suddenly stopped working

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

This installs all the input drivers for X.org.